# Submit button to call function

Tags: javascript, html

My submit button is not doing anything when I click on it. I believe my event listener is correctly established. Any ideas on why it wont do anything?

JS FILE

```
 document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", saveNames());
function saveNames() {
    var player1name = document.getElementById("player1").value;
    var player2name = document.getElementById("player2").value;
    var player3name = document.getElementById("player3").value;
    var player4name = document.getElementById("player4").value;
    var player5name = document.getElementById("player5").value;
    savePlayer(player1name);
    savePlayer(player2name);
    savePlayer(player3name);
    savePlayer(player4name);
    savePlayer(player5name);
    gameScreen(2);
  }
```

HTML FILE:

```
<input type="text"name="p1"><br>
<input type="text"name="p2"><br>
<input type="text"name="p3"><br>
<input type="text"name="p4"><br>
<input type="text"name="p5"><br>
<input id="submitbutton"type="submit" value="Submit">;
```

Comment: What does `saveNames()` return?  You *probably* just want `saveNames` (no parentheses).  But we also don't know what that function does at all, or if it even exists.

Comment: <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">; space

Comment: @David I've added the appropriate information, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're not binding to the function, you're binding to the *result* of the function.  Just pass the function itself, don't invoke it.  (Get rid of the parentheses):

```
document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", saveNames);
```

**Why?**

Because when that one line of code above executes, if you have the errant parentheses then the *first* thing it does is *execute* the `saveNames` function in order to get the *result* to pass to the `addEventListener` function.  And that result is `undefined` because `saveNames` doesn't return anything.

Presumably also that first invocation of the `saveNames` function doesn't visibly do anything (though it does execute) because the inputs have no values in them yet at that time.

Consider as a contrived example:

```
doSomething( doSomethingElse() )
```

This would execute `doSomethingElse()` and then pass its returned result to `doSomething()`.  The same is true when adding event listeners, you're just calling a function like any other function.

Comment: I've added this, the submit button still does not do anything when clicked.

Comment: @stackoverflowoverflow: Then perhaps it's time to debug.  Check your browser's development console.  Are there any errors?  Using your browser's debugger, place a breakpoint on the line which adds the event listener.  Does it find the element to add the event handler to?  Place a breakpoint in the function.  Does it execute?  What happens?

Comment: @stackoverflowoverflow: Wait... `getElementById("player1")`... Do you *have* any elements with that `id`?  You don't in the HTML you're showing.  So I guess when you say that the button "does not do anything" what specifically are you expecting it to do and why?

Comment: That part you are right about, I was getting the wrong ID when saving names and I've fixed that now. However, I'm expecting the submit button to save all player names and then change screens. But still as of now clicking it does nothing, no errors in console

Comment: @stackoverflowoverflow: *"I'm expecting the submit button to save all player names and then change screens"* - Start smaller.  Because none of the functions you're calling are present in the code you're showing.  So don't *assume* the problem is in just the code you're showing.  Again, it's time to debug.  What you *should* be expecting is for the `saveNames` function to be invoked at all.  That's it.  Place a breakpoint in that function and see if it's invoked.  If it is then this code works and your other problem is somewhere else and unrelated to this question.

Comment: So now I'm getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at HTMLBodyElement.document.body.onkeyup (setup.js:118) ..... (Is this because I'm inserting that submit button into the html and adding an event listener before the dom is fully loaded therefore it's null? How do i work around this)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184902/discussion-between-stackoverflow-overflow-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

1. add the listener like this -

   ```
   document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", saveNames);
   ```

note , I have removed () at end.

2. Use Id instead of name. you are reading these elements with id then you need to specify that.
3. Give a spaces before name or type.

Comment: use id instead of name. You use referring these elements by ID so you need to specify it . second give space before id and same thing is before type in button. <input type="text" id='p1'><br>
<input type="text" id="p2"><br>
<input type="text" id="p3"><br>
<input type="text" id="p4"><br>
<input type="text" id="p5"><br>
<input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: Nothing, nothing even comes up in console. Not sure what else to do

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Remove the parenthese after "saveNames" - leaving them will call saveNames when it is encountered
document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", saveNames);

function saveNames() {
  //Use an array as it's neater
  var players = [
    document.getElementById("player1").value,
    document.getElementById("player2").value,
    document.getElementById("player3").value,
    document.getElementById("player4").value,
    document.getElementById("player5").value
  ]

  //loop and save
  players.forEach(function(name) {
    if (name) {
      savePlayer(name);
    }
  });

  //gameScreen(2);
}

function savePlayer(name) {
  console.log(`${name} saved.`);
}
```

```html
<input id="player1" type="text" name="p1"><br>
<input id="player2" type="text" name="p2"><br>
<input id="player3" type="text" name="p3"><br>
<input id="player4" type="text" name="p4"><br>
<input id="player5" type="text" name="p5"><br>
<input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Hi Tommy, I'm still having no luck here. As I mentioned before, This html is being inserted into the page via innerHTML. I'm wondering if the event listener is not working because it's trying to set it before the DOM has inserted the data, but I believe it would try to throw an error and I'm not getting any. This is just confusing because I clearly see your code works.